# enum in separate class in java

Tags: java, enums

I am trying to write two classes:

one for a robot that will instance with unique ID and direction.
and another class for direction that will use enum for the directions for a robot.
I tried to write it in the following way but I think i am missing something...

```
package Q1;

public class Robot {
    static int IDGenerator = 1000;  //ID generator for class Robot
    int RoboID;                     //The ID of the robot
    Direction direction;            //The Direction the robot is facing

    //Constructor for Robot
    public Robot(int dir){
        this.direction = new Direction(dir);
        this.RoboID = IDGenerator;
        IDGenerator++;
    }
}
```

the class for the enum:

```
package Q1;

public enum Direction{
    UP(1), RIGHT(2), DOWN(3), LEFT(4);
    private final int dir;

    //constructor for Direction enum for a robot 
    private Direction(int dir){
        this.dir = dir;
    }

    //return facing direction of a robot
    public int getDirection(){
        return this.dir;
    }
}
```

Comment: if I am defining it as public i get "Illegal modifier for the enum constructor; only private is permitted." compile error

Comment: OK I remembered right after I wrote my previous comment (temporary brain fart) that is why I removed it immediately. Of course only `private` is permitted since `enum` is suppose to be holder of constants of enum type. It would be strange to let user create new instances representing some particular constant if it is already defined in enum.

Answer (score 3):

Enums are not instantiated via `new`; instead, they have a defined set of instances at compile time. Just access the instances directly like this:

```
public Robot(Direction dir) {
    this.direction = dir;
}
```

You call this constructor e.g. like this:

```
Robot bot = new Robot(Direction.UP);
```

Comment: @YuvalLevy Your `Direction` constructor looks fine to me.

Comment: Are the numbers used for anything else? If not, just drop them and the constructor completely.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you don't want to use a `Direction` parameter in your `Robot` constructor, then the classic solution is to provide a static method in your enum to return the right value for a given input:

```
public enum Direction {
    //... code omitted

    public static Direction fromInt(int direction) {
        for (Direction d : values()) {
            if (direction == d.getDirection()) {
                return d;
            }
        }
        throw new NoSuchElementException(Integer.toString(direction));
    }
}
```

Then use this in your constructor:

```
//Constructor for Robot
public Robot(int dir){
    this.direction = Direction.fromInt(dir);
    this.RoboID = IDGenerator;
    IDGenerator++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `this.direction = new Direction(dir);` although the constructor is private. Provide a (static) method in the enum to convert the integer into the correct direction.

Edit: Or use

```
public Robot(Direction direction) {
...
```

instead.

Comment: should he change Robot constructor argument to Direction. because enums are designed not to be created.

Comment: It would still not be necessary to create them. One would call `new Robot(Direction.DOWN)` for example. Creating new instances is indeed not a good idea.

Comment: Just to clarify this: The static method to convert the integer would still not return a new instance, but would rather use Direction.UP etc. to deliver the enum.

Answer (score 0):

try something like

```
package SO;

public class Robot {
    static int IDGenerator = 1000; // ID generator for class Robot
    int RoboID; // The ID of the robot
    Direction direction; // The Direction the robot is facing

    // Constructor for Robot
    public Robot(Direction dir) {
        this.direction = dir;
        this.RoboID = IDGenerator;
        IDGenerator++;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return "Direction: " + direction;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Robot r = new Robot(Direction.UP);
        System.out.println(r);
    }
}
```

Pass direction while creating object of Robot.

Apart from that i personally would have used **Builder pattern** here, something like following

```
package SO;

public class Robot {
    static int IDGenerator = 1000; // ID generator for class Robot
    int RoboID; // The ID of the robot
    Direction direction; // The Direction the robot is facing

    public Robot setDirection(Direction dir){
        this.direction = dir;
        return this;
    }

    public Robot setId(int id){
        this.RoboID = id;
        return this;
    }
    // Constructor for Robot

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return "Direction: " + direction;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Robot r = new Robot();
        r = r.setDirection(Direction.UP).setId(212);
        System.out.println(r);
    }
}
```